# How can I avoid using `eval()` in this example?

Tags: javascript, eval

I'm trying to use a string as a reference to a variable to pass into a function. For example:

```
var names = ['Peter', 'John'],

var hasName = function(name){
    var params = ['names'];
    return $.inArray(name, eval( params[0] )) === -1;
};
```

How to avoid `eval()`?

**EDIT:**

The string from `params[0]` is comming from a `data-qval` of an `input` in my html. The array that contains the actual data can be declared anywhere, `params[0]` is just a reference to that array passed in as string in `data-qval`, it's a parameter. I pasted my plugin's code here .

http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1598528 Line `101`.

Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/ZsS2D/29/

It currently works, I'm just looking for a way get rid of `eval()`...

Comment: It won't work without it. The string from `params[0]` is comming from a `data-` in an `input`

Comment: @ elclanrs: Much better to show the actual code, or at least include that sort of detail from the outset.

Comment: Too much code to paste here. It's just hard to explain what my problem is. Maybe `eval()` is just needed in this case...I put up a pastie tho if it helps. I tried to reduce the problem to the bare minimum,

Comment: @ elclanrs: That's usually best. It's okay if it's a lot of code, just summarize your question at the outset and then show the code after (otherwise people don't read).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>In that particular case, just use `names`:</s>

```
var names = ['Peter', 'John'],
var hasName = function(name){
    var params = ['names'];
    return $.inArray(name, names ) === -1;
};
```

(See also the note below.) *(Your edit makes the above not applicable.)*

If you're trying to look up the `names` array in some container using the string `"names"`, you'd have to have a reference to the container, e.g.:

```
var obj = {
    names: ['Peter', 'John'
};
var hasName = function(name){
    var params = ['names'];
    return $.inArray(name, obj[params[0]] ) === -1;
};
```

If there *is* no container other than the variable scope in which you're doing this, you'll have to use `eval`. But you can (and usually should) adjust things so you have a container (as above) so you can avoid it. Note that if `names` is declared at global scope, you do have a container (`window`).

So to summarize:

1. If `names` is a `var` at global scope (or an [implicit global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)), `window[params[0]]` will give you a reference to it.
2. If `names` is already in some container object, you can use `container[params[0]]` to get a reference to it.
3. If `names` is a `var` within a function, you cannot get at it using a runtime string without `eval`; ideally, rather than `var names = [...];`, use `var container = {names: [...]};` and then you can use `container[params[0]]`.

---

Note that your function is called `hasName`, but it returns `true` when the array **doesn't** have the name and `false` when it does. You probably want `!== -1`, not `=== -1`.

Comment: I see...Seems like I'm stuck with `eval()` because there's no way I can tell where and how is this array going to be declared. Is up to the user using the plugin. The array will typically contain usernames to exclude for validation. Data can come from anywhere, can't know the container...

Comment: @elclanrs: I would change the API of the plugin such that you *can* know when and how `names` is defined. Have the user pass it into the plugin as a configuration parameter or something. But if your code is in a separate plugin file and you're successfully using `eval("names")`, `names` is a global and you can use `window["names"]` to get at it. The only way it could be something other than a global would be if your plugin were a closure over the scope in which `names` is defined, which would require that your plugin code be intermixed with the code defining it.

Comment: Thanks for your help really. What do you think would be the disadvantages of my approach with `eval`? It seems to work with any array declared in any scope so far. ie. `var obj = { arr: [1] }; // eval( 'obj.arr' ) will work!`

Comment: @elclanrs: `eval` is a very big tool. It fires up a JavaScript parser and (on most engines) JIT compiler. Again, in your use case, `window[params[0]]` would do it, but I would **strongly** recommend not forcing the users of your plugin to create global variables for this. This is a clear case where they should pass you the array to check against. (Separately, your line 101 has an error: `!~$.inArray(params[1] === 'true'` will always be `false`; you're using strict equality to test a boolean against a string).

Comment: `!~$.inArray(params[1] === 'true'...` works fine for me...no errors in console or anything. and `window[params[0]]` didn't work. I put up a full working example here http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/ZsS2D/29/.

Comment: @elclanrs: Also, to be clear: It **won't** work with "any scope". It will only work with scopes your code closes over, which if the plug-in is in its own file and included separately from the code that uses it (as it presumably will be) means the only scope in question is global scope. There's a better way to access global scope, so no need for `eval`.

Comment: Oh, I think I get what you mean now. That made it a bit more clear. Yeah I guess it could be a problem later on...

Comment: @elclanrs: *"`!~$.inArray(params[1] === 'true'`... works fine for me"* It'll *work* (in that it won't raise an exception or something), it'll just always be `false`: http://jsbin.com/uwigay Again, if you use *strict* equality to compare a boolean and a string, it will always be false.

Comment: that's not what I'm doing tho. The full expression is `params[1] === 'true' ? value : value.toLowerCase()`. It's just setting `value` to lowercase if `params[1]` is `false` basically. It'll become eventually `~!$.inArray(value, eval( params[0] ))`

Comment: @elclanrs: Sorry, missed that the entire ternary was *within* the call to `isArray`. (Why make them pass the **string** `"true"` rather than a boolean? What purpose is served?)

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this enough?

```
var hasName = function(name){
    return $.inArray(name, names) > -1;
};
```

Also, notice the comparison

> Because JavaScript treats 0 as loosely equal to false (i.e. 0 ==
>   false, but 0 !== false), if we're checking for the presence of value
>   within array, we need to check if it's not equal to (or greater than)
>   -1.

Comment: @ Jakub: There's no need to replace the `!== -1` with `> -1`. [The documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) is clear: *"The `$.inArray()` method...returns `-1` when it doesn't find a match."* So it's not going to return, say, `-2`. You can use `> -1` (or `>= 0`) if you like, but you don't have to.

Comment: Yeah I usually use `!~$.inArray()` I just wanted to make it clear for everybody so more peopl could help

Comment: Yes, but your function writes to the variable called `hasName`, which will have a value of `true` when name is *not* found.

Comment: @JakubKonecki: I see what you mean, I have to admit I missed it was `===` when it should be `!==`.

Comment: @elclanrs: How...oblique. Do you actually dislike the people who will have to maintain your code? ;-)

Comment: lol. `~` it's pretty useful. I actually find it more evident than having to look for that `-1`. It's sort of implied when I see `~` that the function returns `-1`

Comment: @elclanrs: :-) Maybe *you* find it clear. I'm still not sure it works in all cases (or if it does, why). If anyone other than you will maintain the code, I'd **strongly** recommend not doing that sort of thing. But that's way off-topic. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Strings as references to variables? If it's a global object in a browser, it will be in the window object, so you can just do `window[variableName]` to get its value.  Same for objects, i.e. instead of `object.foo`, you can do `object['foo']` or `bar = 'foo', object[bar]`.  For locally scoped variables, you cannot do it without using an object or `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

if `names` is global, you can use the global namespace, i.e. `window`

```
var hasName = function(name,namespace){
    namespace = namespace || window;
    return $.inArray(name, namespace.names) > -1;
};
hasName('Peter'); //=> true;
```

This may also be an idea:

```
var MYNS = { names:['Peter','John']
            ,hasName: function(name){
               return $.inArray(name, this.names) > -1;
             }
           };
 MYNS.hasName('Peter'); //=>true
```